# Why this if condition is not working select options

Tags: jquery, if-statement

```
<select id="slneedbulk" name="slneedbulk" placeholder="Select" value="No" class="thwepof-input-field validate-required">
<option value="">Select</option><option value="No" selected="">No</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select>
```

```
(function($) {
  
    $('#slneedbulk').change(function(){ 
var selop =$(this).children("option:selected").val();

//alert("You have selected " + selop);

if {$((+ selop)=Yes) {

$(".dis-row").css("display", "block"); 

 }else
if {$((+ selop)=No) {

$(".dis-row").css("display", "none"); 

}

});
 
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Should not you use ==

Comment: Your code has basic errors and doesn't run at all `if {` should be `if (`.   Check your IDE for errors or at least the browser console (F12).  Your test `if {$((+ selop)=Yes) {` should be `if (selop=="Yes") {`  it's unclear what `$((+` is indented to do.

Comment: use == instead of = as = is used to assign value and == is used for comparision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making it unnecessarily hard for yourself. The jQuery way is "write less - do more!", see below for my version:

```js
$('#slneedbulk').change(function(){ 
  $(".dis-row").toggle(this.value==="Yes"); 
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="slneedbulk" name="slneedbulk" placeholder="Select" value="No" class="thwepof-input-field validate-required">
<option value="">Select</option><option value="No" selected="">No</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select>

<div class="dis-row">The "need bulk" option was selected.</div>
```

`jQuery.toggle(flag)` usually toggles between "hide" and "show" for the selected element(s), but when a boolean `flag` is present then its value dictates the visibility directly. The `.change()` call without any arguments actually triggers the event handler directly after loading.